# Reading two values and add them together

Tags: c#

The prob is: "Read 2 variables, named A and B and make the sum of these two variables, assigning its result to the variable X. Print X as shown below. Print endline after the result otherwise you will get “Presentation Error”."

```
int A =  Console.Read();
int B =  Console.Read();
int C = A + B;

Console.WriteLine("X = " + C + "\n");
```

I Thought it was as simple as that(cos in c++ is). I am ultimately wrong.

Comment: The input from a console is a string, you have to convert the input to an int: `int A = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Console.ReadLine(); gives you string, convert it to int

Comment: You are reading in strings. If you don't Parse (TryParse) them to numbers then you are not doing a numeric sum but string concat.

Comment: Do i always have to do Convert when i expect to have an input besides a string?

Comment: @IgorCherkasov I you want something to be a number and it is not you will have to Parse/Convert yes

Comment: FYI even though `Console.Read` returns an `int` it's not what you want.  It's basically giving you the Ascii value of a single character.  As mentioned by others you'll want to use `Console.ReadLine` to get the input then parse that to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud convert the string that Console.ReadLine() retrieve from the keyboard in order to have ints:

```
int A =  Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int B =  Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int C = A + B;

Console.WriteLine("X = " + C + "\n");
```

Here is the working example of this code: [working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W05PbT)

Comment: You could also make a direct Console.WriteLine("X = " + A + B + "\n");

Comment: This looks right, not sure why you're getting downvoted

Comment: @ShamPooSham: the man that made other answer juste after me was not fair play and wanted to be first so he downvoted in order to be first with neutral score ;-) He finally deleted his answer and let mine with -1 :-)

Answer (score -3):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. You have to convert it to an int

```
int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

And I'm not sure how `Console.WriteLine()` handles numbers, but just to be sure do

```
Console.WriteLine("X = " + C.ToString() + "\n");
```

***EDIT***
Just checked it out, `Console.WriteLine()` automatically calls the objects `.ToString()` method if it is not a string, therefore

```
Console.WriteLine("X = " + C + "\n");
```

is okay

Comment: The string concatenation will automatically call `ToString` as would `Console.WriteLine` if you pass it something other than a `string`.

Comment: Just checked that out too and updated my answer